# Custom jCarousel causing weird looping effect when clicking on a pager element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jcarousel

Ok, I'll lay this out as easy as I can:

1) Check out this page and view the carousel:

http://www.powellcreative.com/clients/StansellHealth/

2) jCarousel is set up to be circular, has only 3 slides, and starts on the 5th slide (2nd slide, 2nd instance of it [so it will prevent any blank space]

3) It looks great here and works just fine if you click the "1" on the pager.

4) If you start off by clicking "3" however, the carousel moves like it should however the left slide dynamically changes to slide "4" after the animation stops (which is incorrect, it should stay on slide "5" as you are currently on slide "6")

5) If you start off by clicking "1" and then click ANY other number in the pager, the left slide will ALWAYS dynamically change to slide "6" and not the true previous slide prior to the item you click on.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds so confusing for such a simple task, lol!

It sounds to me like you are trying to use a screwdriver to beat a nail into a piece of wood. There is a better way. I would recommend taking a look at something like [Revolver.js](http://revolverjs.com). It's not a content slider, more of a framework for building a slider. Which is what it looks like you're trying to do here.

I realize you did not specifically ask for an alternative solution but I feel strongly about this recommendation and think that it could be a big help to you.

**DISCLAIMER:** I am the lead developer of Revolver.js, and while it might be a tiny bit self-serving to recommend something I made (and it is), I still think it's a good fit for you. This is the reason I started the project in the first place. So please forgive the shameless plug. :)

Comment: LOL, yeah I tend to take the hard way around lol. I'll take a look at Revolver as well. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem at all! There aren't many tools out there like Revolver.js so many people take the "hard way around" because that's all they know. :)

Comment: Now, can Revolver do the same exact thing as I'm wanting?

Comment: Yes, you'd just create a [custom transition](http://revolverjs.com/docs.html#extending_revolver) for it and use the [public properties](http://revolverjs.com/docs.html#public_properties) to manipulate each slide. If you need any help getting started, take a look at Revolver's [built in transitions](https://github.com/johnnyfreeman/revolver/blob/master/jquery.revolver.js#L158) to get an idea about how to build them.